# Função multiexplode com array_intersect retornando elementos nulos

Tags: php

Olá, eu tenho o seguinte script PHP:

**Código:**

```
<?php

$lista1 = ["CURITIBA:SO","SP","BH","RS"];
$lista2 = ["RJ","SC","AM","CURITIBA"];
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {
    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}

for($j=0; $j <= 3; $j++){

    $lista3 = multiexplode(array(":H", ":SO"), $lista1[$j]);
}

$matches = array_intersect($lista3, $lista2);

for($i =0; $i <= 3; $i++){

    if(array_key_exists($i, $matches)){

        echo "O valor encontrado igual foi: $matches[$i]"."</br>";

    }else{

        echo "Não existe valor igual neste elemento da lista"."</br>";
    }

}

?>
```

**Output:**

> Não existe valor igual neste elemento da lista
>     Não existe valor igual neste elemento da lista
>     Não existe valor igual neste elemento da lista
>     Não existe valor igual neste elemento da lista

Acima está a saída, porém se eu alterar a variável `$lista1[$j]` que está dentro de um for que percorre todos os elementos da mesma, ele retorna o valor desejado que é a palavra **CURITIBA** sem **:SO**.

**Alteração:**

```
for($j=0; $j <= 3; $j++){

   $lista3 = multiexplode(array(":H", ":SO"), $lista1[0]);
}
```

Desta forma ele me retorna o valor desejado, porém eu passei o índice manualmente, eu gostaria que ele percorresse todos os índices, pois minha lista real possui cerca de 14 mil elementos cada uma.Como realizar isto no script acima?

[Visualizar código](https://ideone.com/zjXccK)

**Objetivo:**

Existem duas listas com elementos que contém nomes, alguns possuem uma abrevição contém uma sigla do mesmo junto ao nome, ao realizar o match entre essas duas listas deve ser retornado somente o valor do nome que existe entre as duas listas, utilizei uma função multiexplode para remover todos os valores que preciso e após um implode para receber todos os valores em minha terceira lista e conferir os arrays após. Caso alguém consiga deixar esse script mais inteligente, será muito bem-vindo o comentário!

Comment: Como já é a terceira pergunta relacionada a isso, está parecendo que o que está fazendo é um problema XY. Um dos problemas no seu código é fazer a atribuição à `$lista3` dentro do laço e com isso sempre alterará o valor. Desta forma, no `array_interseft` você analisará apenas o último item da lista 1. Esse pode nem ser o único problema, pois parece que você está complicando cada vez mais a solução de algo que pode ser simples, então sugiro que ao invés de perguntar o que há de errado no seu código, você apresente uma descrição detalhada do seu problema.

Comment: entendi, achei uma solução para o problema, obrigado!

Comment: Olá, Vinhali. A formatação do seu post está muito boa, mas o conteúdo ficou confuso (só temos seu texto, o resto só vc sabe) , e provavelmente por falta de informações essenciais tem votos para fechar e negativações. Como você aparenta estar se esforçando para caprichar, eu acredito que estes links podem ajudar na elaboração das suas postagens: Um deles é como fazer um [mcve], e outro deles explica melhor [o que é o ProblemaXY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499), mencionado oportunamente pelo colega @AndersonCarlosWoss - Se conseguir aplicar às suas duvidas, facilitará para obter ajuda.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica, vou melhorar os próximos posts!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Possível solução:**

```
for($j=0; $j <= 3; $j++){

    $lista = implode($lista1);
    $lista3 = multiexplode(array(":SO"), $lista);

}
```

Comment: Poderia completar sua resposta explicando qual era o problema e por que este trecho de código resolveu? O código pode parecer simples para você, mas para outros usuários da comunidade ele pode não fazer sentido, então é sempre interessante você explicar através de texto.

Comment: comento sim, eu demorei para chegar nessa solução e os demais posts não foram objetivos pois a situação problema mudou, os dados vem de BD's diferentes, isso complicou a situação!

Comment: Por isso que eu comentei que isso está parecendo um problema XY. Ao invés de ir na fonte do problema, parece que você está criando uma "solução" que gera outro problema, aí precisa resolver esse outro problema gerando um novo problema... Seria bem mais simples se você descrevesse o real problema que precisa resolver e assim poderíamos saber se o que está fazendo faz sentido ou não. Na minha experiência, dados os códigos que postou nas perguntas, não faz. Parece que está complicando algo que deveria ser simples.

Comment: Descrevi o problema junto a solução, se souber uma maneira de otimizar isso, seria de grande ajuda!

Comment: Essa descrição do problema deveria ser parte da pergunta, não da resposta.

Comment: Post alterado !